# Extract year and week from a string in data.table r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like so

```
dt <- data.table::data.table(
  "year_week" = c("y_9001", "y_9002", "y_9003", "y_9004", "y_9005", "y_9101", "y_9102", "y_9103", "y_9104", "y_9105" )
)
```

I need to make two additional columns, "year" and "week" extracting the year and week from the "year_week" column. I have done the following with ifelse statements, but thats inefficient and one cannot use more than 51 nested ifelse statements.

```
dt[, year := ifelse(stringr::str_detect(year_week, "^y_90"), "1990", 
                    ifelse(str_detect(year_week, "^y_91"), "1991", NA ))]
```

Any suggestions without ifelse statements? Thanks.

Comment: Why is the year corresponding to column value matching `"^y_90"` equal to `"1991"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `substr` function:

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  "year_week" = c("y_9001", "y_9002", "y_9003", "y_9004", "y_9005", "y_9101", "y_9102", "y_9103", "y_9104", "y_9105" )
)
dt[, year := substr(year_week, 3, 4)][
   , week := substr(year_week, 5, 6)]
dt
#>     year_week year week
#>  1:    y_9001   90   01
#>  2:    y_9002   90   02
#>  3:    y_9003   90   03
#>  4:    y_9004   90   04
#>  5:    y_9005   90   05
#>  6:    y_9101   91   01
#>  7:    y_9102   91   02
#>  8:    y_9103   91   03
#>  9:    y_9104   91   04
#> 10:    y_9105   91   05
```

Since I don't know what years are covered in your dataset, you'll need to decide whether it is safe to simply paste "19" in front of all years, or if you sometimes need to paste "20" for a different century.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> dt %>% mutate(year = paste0(19,as.numeric(substr(year_week, 3,4))), 
  week = (as.numeric(substr(year_week, 5,6))))
    year_week year week
 1:    y_9001 1990    1
 2:    y_9002 1990    2
 3:    y_9003 1990    3
 4:    y_9004 1990    4
 5:    y_9005 1990    5
 6:    y_9101 1991    1
 7:    y_9102 1991    2
 8:    y_9103 1991    3
 9:    y_9104 1991    4
10:    y_9105 1991    5
```

Comment: This should work but the question is tagged `data.table`...

Comment: I know, but :> dat <- dt %>% mutate(year = paste0(19,as.numeric(substr(year_week, 3,4))), week = (as.numeric(substr(year_week, 5,6)))) > class(dat)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> , if the OP wants the end result then it should be fine I guess.

Answer (score 0):

would this work? easy and simple but a bit slow if your df is monumentally huge

```
library(stringr)

dt$year<-paste0(19, str_sub(dt$year_week, 3L, 4L))
dt$week<-str_sub(dt$year_week, 5L, -1L)

dt     

    year_week year week
 1:    y_9001 1990   01
 2:    y_9002 1990   02
 3:    y_9003 1990   03
 4:    y_9004 1990   04
 5:    y_9005 1990   05
 6:    y_9101 1991   01
 7:    y_9102 1991   02
 8:    y_9103 1991   03
 9:    y_9104 1991   04
10:    y_9105 1991   05
```